# Mindray 5150 disconnecting every some days

Tags: ip, connectivity, lis

I have connected a Mindray 5150 with LIS system and its working but the Mindray owner calling me every some days (it is random, maybe 2 days, maybe 15 days) that the system is not connected and the only way to reconnect it is to change both devices (server and analyser) IP.

Can you know or imagine what can cost this issue?

I installed the same analyser to other clients and they don't have this problem. I even check the settings that they are the same but i think that something my client does and changing the procedure, but i don't know what.

Always the problem happen to the first connection of the day (not during the established connection).

I have try to each device separately to change IP and change it back to the before one but not working, i reboot our system (LIS), i reboot analyser.

The only way to work is to give a new IP to both sites.

Thank you